# "Sequence contains no matching element" setting HasColumnType("varchar") in EF Mappings using Effort

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, effort

I have the following Entity Framework (v6.1.3) mapping:

```
public class FileStoreDocumentEntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FileStoreDocumentEntity>
{
    public FileStoreDocumentEntityMapping()
    {
        Property(x => x.FileStoreDownloadUrl)
            .HasColumnName("FileStoreDetailsUrl")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(1000);
        Property(x => x.FileStoreVersion)
            .HasColumnName("FileStoreVersion")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

Both columns are of data type = "varchar" in my database and sizes are correct:
[image]

However, some of my unit tests are failing with this error:

"*System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element*"

I read in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982749/sequence-contains-no-matching-element-entityframework) that you can get the error above if you pass an invalid type to the `HasColumnType` method but in my case "varchar" should be valid.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Here is how those properties are defined in my entity:

```
    public virtual string FileStoreVersion
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string FileStoreDetailsUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Here is an example of one test that fails in the first line:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_ReturnsSuccess()
    {
        _context.DistributionListSelectionCriteriaDepartmentEntities.Add(_distributionListSelectionCriteriaDepartmentEntity);
```

`_context` in this case is of type `MemoryEnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext`:

```
    private void InitializeTestObjects()
    {
        _context = new MemoryEnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext();
```

Which inherits from my `public class EnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext : DbContext`

That class is where i'm initializing my entity mappings:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FileStoreDocumentEntityMapping());
```

Could this be because I'm using **Effort** MemoryContext vs a Real DB context?

```
public class MemoryEnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext : EnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext
{
    public MemoryEnterprisePaycorCodeFirstContext()
        : base(DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient())
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Would it be possible to share the code that throws the error from your unit test?

Comment: @philreed I just added those details. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. On which line are you seeing the error `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element`?

Comment: First line of the test method I put in my post adding an item to `DistributionListSelectionCriteriaDepartmentEntities`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what it was. Turns out that I was using `Effort` library which does not support some Column Types as pointed out by @Balah. I used his technique to bypass the entity mapping configuration when coming from my Memory Context:
[Effort (EF Unit Testing) giving errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893911/effort-ef-unit-testing-giving-errors)